# How to download a magnet / get its URL

Tags: google-chrome, utorrent

I use utorrent via Chrome, with localhost gui (`http://localhost:8080/gui`).

How do I get magnets url?
And how do I download them in a `.torrent` form so I will be able to download them with utorrent?

Comment: A magnet link is not an URL. Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme). You don't download them in torrent form, that is a completely different mechanism.

Comment: More to the point, this is not a Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your Magnet download into utorrent is triggered by clicking the magnet icon or whatever when you download it. You can do `Right click -> copy link` (or whatsoever), then you can paste it to a magnet to torrent tool, I found [this](http://magnet2torrent.me/) on google, but i'm sure there are tons of them out there.